# How to remove a file from VLC playlist once it has finished playing?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have a playlist that I am automatically adding songs into and that is playing 24/7. I would like to remove the files from that playlist also automatically once they have finished playing.

How can I do that?

Should I use a plugin/CMD/batch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you automatically adding the songs?

Comment: With a CMD command. `vlc --one-instance --playlist-enqueue "%PATH/TO/FILE%"`